# Minimal API with async static method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, minimal-apis

When we create something like this in NET 7:

```
app.MapPost("/test", SomeEndpoint.Test);
```

This is my SomeEndpoint.Test:

```
public static class SomeEndpoint
{
    public static IResult Test(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var form = httpContext.Request.ReadFormAsync().Result;
        return Results.Ok(form);
    }
}
```

then anything works well. But I want to have it async, so now my `SomeEndpoint.Test` looks as below:

```
public static class SomeEndpoint
{
    public static async Task<IResult> Test(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var form = await httpContext.Request.ReadFormAsync();
        return Results.Ok(form);
    }
}
```

Boom. That's not working, I always get 200 OK response (even if I change my `Results.Ok` to `Results.BadRequest`). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is known (but not well-known) bug, it was supposed to be fixed in .NET 7 but it is still there (check the duplicates).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are seeing appears to be related to the fact that you are passing extra arguments at all. Removing the `HttpContext` also causes your sample to work.

When passing parameters to an async static method like that, it seems that you are forced to provide the `CancellationToken` parameter otherwise it won't match for `Task`-based method groups.

The following works:

```cs
public static class SomeEndpoint
{
    public static async Task<IResult> Test(
        HttpContext httpContext, 
        CancellationToken token)
    {
        var form = await httpContext.Request.ReadFormAsync(token);
        return Results.Ok(form);
    }
}
```

Comment: @GuruStron I reproduced OP's issue here on a brand new .NET7 project.

Comment: Then they have not fixed it for POST, only for GET)

Comment: It seems that they [have not fixed it at all](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45373) (though it was working in one of the previews as far as I remember)